# Keycloak very high resource usage in Docker

Tags: docker, keycloak

Keycloak server when running in Docker uses 500MB of memory even when it is not doing anything. Same behavior on Docker running in Windows 10 and in Linux CentOS machines. Im using this docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local

services:
  postgres:
      image: postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
        POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
        DB_ADDR: postgres
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_SCHEMA: public
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: Pa55w0rd
        # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
        #JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=true"
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

Dockerfile taken from Keycloak example: https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-postgres.yml
[Png of docker resource usage when running this DockerCompose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG81v.png)

Is it normal resource usage to be so high? Is it something wrong with the example?

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: The documentation of Keyclock states, that the system requirements are "at least 512M of RAM"

Comment: Thank you for your input, it cleared my concerns.